# Matrix Multiplication Error in Java

Tags: java, matrix, matrix-multiplication

i search the net and there is a lot of error like mine. But i cant find the exact solution for matrix multiplication. I use below code for it. i have a lot of matrix multiplication. First i get tranpose of matris A which is ATP. then multiply with P like

n1=ATP*P;

then multiply n1 with A.

N1=n1*A;

When using below code i get right solution i check it with matlab. but multiplication of n1 and A gives error.

P matrix like P={{100,0,0,0...}{0,100,0,0...},......{...0,0,100}}

What is the problem?

Thanks a lot.

```
 public static double[][] multiply(double[][] a, double[][] b) {

    int rowsa = a.length;
    int columnsa = a[0].length;
    int rowsb = b.length;
    int columnsb = b[0].length;
    double c[][] = new double[rowsa][columnsb];

    try {

        if (columnsa == rowsb) {

            for (int ii = 0; ii < rowsa; ii++) {
                for (int jj = 0; jj < columnsb; jj++) {
                    c[ii][jj] = 0;
                    for (int kk = 0; kk < rowsb; kk++) {
                        c[ii][jj] += a[ii][kk] * b[kk][jj];
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Matris is empty");
    }

    return c;
}
```

I call the code like

```
        double ATP[][] = transpose(A);
        double n1[][] = multiply(ATP, PP);
        double N1[][] = multiply(n1, A);
        double n2[][] = multiply(n1, ll);
        double N11[][] = inverse(N1);
        double kats[][] = multiply(N11, n2);
```

i cant give values of A because it is changeable i read time and according to time i calculate tle elements of matrix. Every step add a row to A matrix.it starts with A(4,56)and continue like A(5,56)

Comment: It is always nice to describe the error you encounter.

Comment: Not enough code shown: need to see the initialization of n1 and A and how you call multiply.

Comment: By the way, since you are using `double` and not `Double` arrays, the line `c[ii][jj] = 0;` shouldn't be necessary. The items of an `double` Array are equal to `0`when it is created while the items of a `Double` Array have `null`as initial value.

Comment: @laune Good point! I was about to write it too!

Comment: In order to complete my first comment, may I ask you if your error is an Exception? (You should trace correctly. The message you write doesn't seem pertinent to me.). If not, do you mean the result you get is incorrect?

Comment: i added calling code. my error is not exception. Calculation values is wrong. For example it might be 64 but it gives 8. And after 18 rows it gives Nan value. Sorry about my english

Comment: @ C.Champagne i am confused because it works with n1 but does not work with N1. A dimension is (5,56) P is (5*5) result n1 is (56,5) and N1 is (56,56). I delete the code c[ii][jj] = 0; but i got same error.